# nestjs e2e tests failed because of redis and mongodb connection error randomly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, redis, jestjs, nestjs

I was writing many e2e tests with jest on the nestjs framework, in this project we use [nest-mongodb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nest-mongodb) and [redis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@liaoliaots/nestjs-redis)

after writing multiple tests, when I ran `npm run test:e2e` I faced the below errros.

```
● Test suite failed to run

    MongoPoolClosedError: Attempted to check out a connection from closed connection po
```

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    MongoPoolClosedError: Attempted to check out a connection from closed connection pool
```

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    MongoExpiredSessionError: Cannot use a session that has ended
```

tests written like below:

```js
beforeAll(async () => {
        const moduleFixture = await Test.createTestingModule({
            imports: [AppModule],
        }).compile();

        app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
        app.useGlobalPipes(
            new CustomValidationPipe({
                transform: true,
                whitelist: true,
                validateCustomDecorators: true,
            }),
        );

        await app.init();
    });

    afterAll(async () => {
        await app.close();
    });
```

After running the tests, I shouldn't see any connection errors

Comment: There is not much in the set, so it must be a race condition in your application. There are number of ways how it can happen, but speculating, it's likely the driver tries to `processWaitQueue` after nest closes the poll in `onApplicationShutdown` event handler

Comment: how can I wait till the application closes the queue and then start the next e2e spec? because I realized that after ```app.close()``` on afterAll cause this problem

Comment: yeah, it makes sense. Do you have any tests, or is it the whole thing? async AfterAll should wait for all async tests to resolve, which in turn will wait for beforeAll promises. I wonder if the error you experience is due to the lack of tests themself. It may just break the promise chain and is kinda edge case. It wouldn't wonder me much if jest wasn't tested much for cases without test scenarios.

Comment: I already have multiple e2e tests, about 370 tests, I run this tests with ```--maxWorkers=1``` so it shouldn't happen because node instances. I don't get why this errors happen.